# Distinct types of all created nodes and relationships in Memgraph's database

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

Where can I find Memgraph's docs to list all distinct types of all created nodes and relationships from a graph in database? I found this: https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/connecting-nodes and if I create nodes and relationships using that - I'd like to know how to retrieve all distinct node types and relationships from that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the distinct labels with the following query:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN DISTINCT labels(n);
```

And you can get the relationship types with:

```
MATCH ()-[r]-() RETURN DISTINCT type(r);
```